# Angular ngFor over Map with keyvalues pipe in original map order

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a problem with the keyvalues pipe in angular 11.

I have a map like this:

```
0: {604 => Object}
key: 604
value: {isHiddenByFilter: false, sliderIndex: 0}
1: {709 => Object}
key: 709
value: {isHiddenByFilter: false, sliderIndex: 1}
2: {687 => Object}
key: 687
value: {isHiddenByFilter: false, sliderIndex: 2}
3: {676 => Object}
key: 676
value: {isHiddenByFilter: false, sliderIndex: 3}
4: {682 => Object}
key: 682
value: {isHiddenByFilter: false, sliderIndex: 4}
```

And I iterate using ngFor over it:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let postMap of mappingMap.organisations | keyvalue: originalOrder; let i = index">
                        {{log(mappingMap.organisations)}}
                        {{log(postMap.key)}}
```

This is the originalOrder function:

```
originalOrder = (a: KeyValue<number,MappingMapvalue>, b: KeyValue<number,MappingMapvalue>): number => 0;
```

The organisations map has the correct order and all works fine in ionic serve, but on a real android device, with the same data, the order of organisations is correct, too. But some of the elements of ngFor have the wrong data. They are from another index of the map.

You can compare both logs I created directly in the ngFor loop:

```
{{log(mappingMap.organisations)}}: (Only once here, but it is always the same)
0: {604 => Object}
1: {709 => Object}
2: {687 => Object}
3: {676 => Object}
4: {682 => Object}

{{log(postMap.key)}}:
log bla 633
log bla 604
log bla 687
log bla 676
```

Why is the ngFor order not the same as in the map? Is the originalOrder function wrong? And why appears this problem only in the emulator? Is this coincidence?

Thanks very much for every help.

EDIT:

I tried some more things:

log in the originalOrder function:

```
originalOrder(a: KeyValue<number,MappingMapvalue>, b: KeyValue<number,MappingMapvalue>): undefined {
        console.log('inorder', a.key);
        return undefined;
    }
```

gives this result:

```
inorder 604
inorder 591
inorder 687
inorder 676
inorder 682
inorder 683
inorder 576
inorder 709
inorder 648
inorder 643
inorder 642
inorder 599
```

But correct order of organisations map is:

```
 0: {604 => Object}
1: {709 => Object}
2: {687 => Object}
3: {676 => Object}
4: {682 => Object}
5: {683 => Object}
6: {576 => Object}
7: {633 => Object}
8: {648 => Object}
9: {643 => Object}
10: {642 => Object}
11: {581 => Object}
12: {599 => Object}
13: {591 => Object}
length: 14
```

I also tried return 0 in originalOrder function. That gives a similar result. Not the same but also wrong order.

Comment: Are you using a Map or an object?

Comment: I use a map to have save order of the properties